# Unable to fetch secrets from google secret manager in spring application

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, google-secret-manager

I'm trying to fetch secrets from Google secret manager but they are fetching it just simply shows the secret name

so these all the modifications i did here in my pox.xml i added these dependencies

```
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-secretmanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-secretmanager -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-cloud-secretmanager</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

and this here is my bootstrap-sol.test.properties

```
spring.cloud.gcp.secretmanager.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gcp.secretmanager.bootstrap.enabled=true
```

```
spring.cloud.gcp.secretmanager.secret-name-prefix=sm://
```

and this is how im fetching the secrets in my sol.test.properties

```
jdbc.username=${sm://application-jdbc-username}
jdbc.password=${sm://application-jdbc-password}
```

and in GCP i have Secret Manager Viewer & Secret Manager Secret Accessor permission